# Loading a bitmap icon from resources in an icon handler shell extension

Tags: windows, winapi, shell-extensions

I need to load a `.bmp` icon from resources in `IExtractIcon::Extract`, but I cannot figure out why it is not working. I keep getting a black or white rectangle where the icon is supposed to be.

[image]

I have two icons declared in project resources `.rc` file: `ICON_16_BITMAP` and `ICON_BITMAP`. The icons should definitely be loaded as they are not null after `LoadImageW`.

```
// IExtractIcon

HRESULT icon_handler::GetIconLocation(UINT u_flags, PWSTR psz_icon_file, UINT cch_max, int* pi_index, UINT* pw_flags)
{
    *pw_flags = GIL_NOTFILENAME | GIL_DONTCACHE;
    return S_OK;
}

extern HINSTANCE global_h_instance;

HRESULT icon_handler::Extract(PCWSTR psz_file, UINT n_icon_index, HICON* phicon_large, HICON* phicon_small, UINT n_icon_size)
{
    const int small_size = HIWORD(n_icon_size);
    const int large_size = LOWORD(n_icon_size);

    if (phicon_large != nullptr)
    {
        OutputDebugStringW((L"Extract large icon: " + std::to_wstring(large_size)).c_str());

        *phicon_large = HICON(LoadImageW(global_h_instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ICON_BITMAP), IMAGE_BITMAP, large_size, large_size,
            LR_SHARED));
    }
    if (phicon_small != nullptr)
    {
        OutputDebugStringW((L"Extract small icon: " + std::to_wstring(small_size)).c_str());

        *phicon_small = HICON(LoadImageW(global_h_instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ICON_16_BITMAP), IMAGE_BITMAP, small_size, small_size,
            LR_SHARED));
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

I've tried to follow many tutorials, but this seems as simple I can go but so far it's not working out. Is there anything that sticks out that could be the reason the icon is not working?

Comment: Why do you think it is correct to cast HBITMAP to HICON?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I saw too many references to "HBITMAP being interchangeable with HICON" when searching for a solution. I changed question to loading .ico now.

Comment: (I am not a C++ dev) Is it correct checking: if (phicon_small/large == nullptr) ? Maybe it should look like "if (*phicon_small/large == 0)"

Comment: Ok, I totally messed something up with `.rc` and corresponding `.h` and managed to break them. Simply using `.ico` works fine now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BMP is not the same as the icon format.

> It cannot be forced to convert with HICON.

The easiest way is to convert the BMP file into an icon file by converting the image tool and then load it into the resource.